# Nondeterministic final automat - example

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Show a possibly nondeterministic FA to accept the following language:

$$\left\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:w\text{ contains at least one instance of }aaba,bbb,\text{ or }ababa\right\}$$

Comment: Hi. What have you tried?

Comment: This language is the union of three simpler languages: the language words that contain $aaba$; the language of words that contain $bbb$; and the language of words that contain $ababa$. Can you design FAs for each of these three languages? If so, it’s easy to combine them into a non-deterministic FA that accepts your language.